# How to find the maximum digit of an integer?

Tags: python, integer

If the integer is 2013, then the maximum number would be 3.

How would I proceed to doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
max([int(c) for c in str(2013)])
```

First you convert the number to a string, this allows to look at every digit one by one, then you convert it into a list of single digits and look for the maximum.

Another solution is

```
max = -1

for c in str(2013):
    i = int(c)
    if i > max:
        max = i
```

Comment: This answer works, but please don't use `max` as a variable name.